# FeedMe + Google Maps plugin Address fields missing

Tags: plugin-smartmap, plugin-googlemaps

Just upgraded to GoogleMaps plugin (from SmartMap) and trying to replicate FeedMe feeds.

When I go to assign field -> feed element, I see

- my regular entry field
- I don't see the address sub fields, but rather just a singular address field.

I don't see the subfields as displayed here:
https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/google-maps/guides/importing-addresses/#feed-me

Halp?

Comment: Hi Charlie, the Feed Me integration isn't 100% in place yet, sorry! I'm expecting to release it within the next couple of days. I have a forked version of Feed Me (which totally works), feel free to DM me on Discord for access. The only reason I haven't submitted it as a PR yet is because I may pivot and change how it's handled internally.

Comment: After careful review, I decided to submit the [pull request](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/pull/818) as is. With any luck, someone from Pixel & Tonic will accept the PR within the next few days. I'll post an official answer below when it goes live.

Comment: My pull request was accepted, and released with Feed Me v4.3.6. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news! The two plugins are now fully compatible as of **Feed Me v4.3.6**.

Update to the [latest version](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#436---2021-03-05) of Feed Me, and give it another shot!

Comment: Worked brilliantly! Well done! Definitely a useful combination of tools.